# India vehicle number input Validation and Formatted using html and css

Tags: html, css, angularjs, sass

[image]I want to HTML CSS input look like this formate in HTML input: GJ-05-ES-9658
I need to use between character use dash -
and I want to output like GJ05ES9658 for store unique vehicle Numbers.
If need Javascript to use Angularjs.

I have expression:

```
vnumber: [
      this.vehicleno,
      [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(
          "(([A-Za-z]){2,3}(|-)(?:[0-9]){1,2}(|-)(?:[A-Za-z]){2}(|-)([0-9]){1,4})|(([A-Za-z]){2,3}(|-)([0-9]){1,4})"
        ),
      ],
    ],
```

add auto dash when type

Comment: What have you already tried? Please share any relevant code.

Comment: Use ng-pattern to check the input with regualar expression validation.

Comment: Sir expression i have but input show like GJ-05-RT-8965

Comment: i edit with new suggetion

Comment: Please Read question Proper